# Is there such a word as かなまや or かなまゆ?

Tags: words

In the manga I'm reading, there's a part that I can't decipher if the character is Ya or Yu. I tried searching, かなまや or かなまゆ, but there seem to be no such word.

The context before the statement was said is that the female protagonists thinks that she's stronger than the male protagonist. But she is not definitely sure because, the male protagonist always refuses to have a fighting match with her. In this statement the female protagonist is so angry to the point of grabbing the male protagonist in the collar and is challenging him to have a fight with her. But the male protagonist just keeps on declining.

I place the screenshot of the manga below.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are referring to the handwritten part, it says:

> ゴカイとかなきゃっ

which is:

> [誤解]{ごかい}[解]{と}かなきゃっ

meaning:

> "Gotta clear his/their misunderstanding."

「解かなきゃ」＝「解かなきゃならない」＝「解かなければならない」

The small っ at the end is for informal emphasis, which is used very often.